# Set future from callback

Tags: java, concurrency, future

I want to achieve what the following pseudo code illustrates:

```
int functionA() {
    Future res;
    // ...
    setCallbackForSomething(new Callback() {
        public void onCall() {
            // ...
            res = 5;
        }
    });
    // ...
    return doSomethingElse(res.get());
}
```

i.e. the functionA blocks until the callback has been called, then processes the result and returns something.

Is something like that possible with `Future`? The usual usage,

```
Future res = executor.submit(...);
...
res.get()
```

does not seem to work here. I also cannot change the fact that I have to set the callback like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Future` has limited features. From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)

> A `Future` represents the result of an asynchronous computation. Methods
>   are provided to check if the computation is complete, to wait for its
>   completion, and to retrieve the result of the computation.

It only exposes read operations (except for `cancel`). You won't be able to achieve what you want with `Future`.

Instead, since Java 8, you can use [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)

> A `Future` that may be explicitly completed (setting its value and
>   status), and may be used as a `CompletionStage`, supporting dependent
>   functions and actions that trigger upon its completion.

You initialize the `CompletableFuture`

```
CompletableFuture<Integer> res = new CompletableFuture<>();
```

and complete it either [normally](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#complete-T-) or [exceptionally](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#completeExceptionally-java.lang.Throwable-)

```
setCallbackForSomething(new Callback() {
    public void onCall() {
        // ...
        res.complete(5); // or handle exception
    }
});
```

Instead of calling `get`, you can [chain a completion task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenAccept-java.util.function.Consumer-) on the `CompletableFuture` to call `doSomethingElse`.

```
res.thenAccept(value -> doSomethingElse(value));
```

Though you can still call [`get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#get--) if you want to, blocking until the future is completed.

---

Before Java 8, the Guava library provided [`SettableFuture`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/26.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/SettableFuture.html) to achieve the "set" part of a promised value. But it's also a [`ListenableFuture`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/26.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html) so you can chain other operations on completion.